# Visual Studio enable debug exceptions through macro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, macros, visual-studio, exception

In Visual Studio I would like to break on certain exception while in debug mode.  This is configured through the "Debug >> Exceptions" dialog window (see image below).  Can enabling and disabling these checkboxes be controlled through a macro?  I would like to add a button to a toolbar to control the enable/disable of these with just one click.

[image]

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920391/script-to-enable-disable-breaking-on-specific-exception-types-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a macro to toggle exceptions on or off by using the ExceptionSettings class. The problem seems to be that using the macro is really slow. The following links has code to get you started with this.

[Customizing Exception Handling in the VS Debugger - John Robbins' Blog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/04/03/customizing-exception-handling-in-the-vs-debugger.aspx)
[Fixing Debug > Exceptions settings programmatically - code.logos.com](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/09/fixing_debug_exceptions_settings_programmatically.html)

Comment: Thank You. You will need the "Debugger3" interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte90.debugger3.aspx  And here is a quick snip in case the blog goes down: Sub BreakWhenThrown(Optional ByVal strException As String = "")
    Dim dbg As Debugger3 = DTE.Debugger
    Dim eg As ExceptionSettings = _
        dbg.ExceptionGroups.Item("Common Language Runtime Exceptions")
    eg.SetBreakWhenThrown(True, eg.Item(strException))
End Sub