# Script to enable/disable breaking on specific exception types in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I currently use the Debug -> Exceptions dialog to stop VS from breaking for certain exceptions types. This works perfectly. The problem comes in that occasionally I would like to debug those exceptions, or accidentally turn all exceptions on or off, I then have to hunt through the list and disable the specific exceptions from scratch.

Is there a way to do this with a script of some sort? So that I can add whichever options to a list and toggle then on or off easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a macro that uses the EnvDTE.Debugger3 interface.  This sample one turns on the break for a NullReferenceException, written out to make the intermediate steps obvious:

```
Sub SetNullReferenceExceptionTrap()
    Dim dbg As Debugger3 = DTE.Debugger
    Dim group As ExceptionSettings = dbg.ExceptionGroups.Item("Common Language Runtime Exceptions")
    Dim except As ExceptionSetting = group.Item(GetType(System.NullReferenceException).FullName)
    group.SetBreakWhenThrown(True, except)
End Sub
```

To turn it off, pass False as the first argument.